# OL3:How to judge a point feature in a specific vector source?

Tags: openlayers-3

In my website builded with ol3, I have two or more vector layers with different sources in my map, i want to click features in a **specific** source and show some popup. My way is adding a single click event on my map, and using  `source.getFeaturesAtCoordinate(evt.coordinate)` but always get empty results [].What can i do in this situation?

Comment: Whether each vector layer is configured to one source only(not same)? Whether any source switching is going on using `setSource()` method?

Comment: @SumanthShastry for example, i have two different vector sources, and two vector layers using them, i add both of them to my map, and how to determin a point feature in which source after click-chose?

Answer (score 0):

For points, you would need to be extremely lucky to hit the exact coordinate. You need to consider the rendered size of your points, and for that you'd better use `ol.Map#forEachFeatureAtPixel()`. It works on the layer, not the source:

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
  // get the source
  source = layer.getSource();
  // do something with the feature
});
```